# Azure Event Hub - Receiving events Sequentially

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-eventhub

I am using below code receive the events from Azure Event-Hub

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-framework-getstarted-send#receive-events

**I want to Handle the requests coming to event-hub Sequentially**. For example someone sent 5 events in very quick time, I want to complete request 1 processing then i want take the second request to process.

How can i handle the events coming to event-hub Sequentially?

Answer (score 2):

Event Hub uses partitions to enable horizontal scaling of event processing. You can specify number of partitions during the event hub creation from 1 to 32. Message order is guaranteed only within a partition but not across all partitions.

If you need the order to be maintained, you need to write events only to a specific partition and read only from the same partition. In Azure Event Hub, partitions are distributed across different instances for high availability. Which means, a partition may go offline for maintenance and come online later. So if you wanted to manage order, you need to write and read to a single partition and you may need to manually manage situations such as partition go offline from your application logic.

If you need to manage order, I would recommend using Azure Service Bus queue which order & availability is managed by Service bus it self.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide),

In order to make it sequential you need to select the proper partitionKey

> If you don't specify a partition key when publishing an event, a
>   round-robin assignment is used. In many cases, using a partition key
>   is a good choice if event ordering is important. When you use a
>   partition key, these partitions require availability on a single node,
>   and outages can occur over time; for example, when compute nodes
>   reboot and patch.

Answer (score 0):

In the bundle of events you receive from eventhub, there is an attribute called `sequence_number`, as this bundle is a list, you can sort by `sequence_number` and then process the events.